# Updating columns consisted of rows & Replaced with the new values Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-update, insert-update

I have a big data that i imported from SQL database. The purpose is to convert some of the columns from HEX to float, then turn the whole data into .txt file.

Now, here's an example on what I have:

```
No    A        B         C
0   data1   0x58414587  0x27851588
1   data2   0x56565565  0x98529887
2   data3   0x97199000  0x98519771
3   data4   0x41149932  0x68719870
```

So, I managed to convert column B and column C into other values using python. But, the problem is how to update it on the table and then convert the whole data into .txt file. 
and I want it to be like this(just assume the values are right)

```
No    A         B         C
0   data1   1687, 1690  2323, 2326
1   data2   2055, 2056  2567, 2680
2   data3   2890, 2899  2990, 2995
3   data4   1002, 1010  1788, 1790
```

After doing the converting on Python, I get the values of column B in variable `row_list`, which consists of a list of the float results, from this piece of code

```
for i in range(ln):
    row=cursor.fetchval()
    result=slicing_bin(row)
    result_float = [float("{0:.2f}".format(i)) for i in result]
    row_list.append(result_float)
```

So, what should i write to update column b & c?
thankyou 
if i miss something, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have an id of the SQL records? You can do an update on the id in database. Then convert to txt is even more simpler just create a a file and dump the values in it.

Comment: So, do you mean I should update column B and C from python to database, then convert altogether to txt?

Comment: Yeah you can update in batches since your data is huge.

Comment: okay, will try to figure it out, thanks !